# Why is XPath count() always returning the same value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm creating an XSL file that makes a number of query XPath to an XML document and I have some fields that I have to count the total number of such field for example field book (number of books published).

Example of tree in XML:

```
<DADOS-AUTOR NOME="Rui Carlos Correia" ID="267">
    <PRODUCAO-BIBLIOGRAFICA>
        <TRABALHOS-EM-EVENTOS>
             <TRABALHO-EM-EVENTOS.......
        <ARTIGOS-PUBLICADOS>
             <ARTIGO-PUBLICADO..........
```

I have this XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <BODY>
        <H1>Lista de Autores</H1>
        <TABLE border="1">
          <TR>
            <TD><B>Nome do Autor</B></TD>
            <TD><B>ID do Autorr</B></TD>
            <TD><B>Publicações de Artigos</B></TD>
          </TR>
          <xsl:for-each select="//DADOS-AUTOR">
            <TR>
              <TD><xsl:value-of select="@NOME"/></TD>
              <TD><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></TD>
              <TD><xsl:value-of select="count(//ARTIGO-PUBLICADO)"/></TD>
            </TR>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </TABLE>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that the function count must return the total number of articles of all authors (I have some 20 authors in total) but the number that appears in the table for each  author line is always the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post enough code (XML+XSLT) to enable us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
count(//ARTIGO-PUBLICADO)
```

to

```
count(.//ARTIGO-PUBLICADO)
```

if you want to count only the `ARTIGO-PUBLICADO` elements beneath the current `DADOS-AUTOR` context element rather than counting all `ARTIGO-PUBLICADO` elements in the entire document.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the count function for count(.//ARTIGO-PUBLICADO) but now appears 0 in the field. Exploring the all xml document the autor "Rui Carlos Correia" has 3 articles, for example the next autor "David Filipe Gouveia" has 6 articles... but this function returns 0.

Comment: You'll have to follow the advice of @michael.hor257k and edit your question to include a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.